# выгрузить архив писем с gmail

Tags: gmail

Подскажите как сделать офлайн копию своих переписок в gmail на локальный ПК?

Comment: https://takeout.google.com/ ?

Comment: Поставить любого почтового клиента. Подключиться. Включить IMAP. Синхронизироваться.